# Delegate to open 2 message boxes parameterless simultaneously

Tags: c#, delegates

I am attempting to learn the usage of delegates, All the code examples I have seen use parameters to pass on to the internal methods,

The goal of the example is to open 2 messageboxes on form launch without passing parameters
here is the code I have tried but I dont know how to call internal functions

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Messageboxes2
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Delegation delegated = new Delegation();
        delegated.
    }

}
class Delegation
{    
    public delegate string mbox ();

    static void msgboz1(mbox d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1rstBox");
    }
    static void msbox2(mbox d)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("2ndbox");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: why you are sending delegate to method as parameter?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of events ......

Comment: I am trying to fire the messageboxes..

Answer (score 0):

Simply passing delegate as a parameter does not call the method.
You better learn more about delegates, you can try following for better understanding.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Delegation.Invoke(Delegation.msgboz1);
    Delegation.Invoke(Delegation.msbox2);
}

}
class Delegation
{    
public delegate void mbox ();

public static void msgboz1()
{
    MessageBox.Show("1rstBox");
}
public static void msbox2()
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("2ndbox");
}
public static void Invoke(mbox method)
{ 
    method();
}
}
```

EDIT:
You can use BeginInvoke method to call methods asynchronously.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Delegation.MethodCaller mc1 = new Delegation.MethodCaller(Delegation.Method1);
        Delegation.MethodCaller mc2 = new Delegation.MethodCaller(Delegation.Method2);
        mc1.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        mc2.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Delegation
    {
        public delegate void MethodCaller();

        public static void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method 1 Invoked");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Method 1 Completed");
        }
        public static void Method2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method 2 Invoked");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Method 2 Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The boxes appeared one ofter another and NOT simultanlessly but thanks.

Comment: You are not able to get 2 message boxes appear simultaneously.

Comment: One way to do it is  Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(msgboz1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(msbox2));
        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();

Comment: Ok, if you want using delegates to call method asynchoronously, you can use BeginInvoke method, see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove parameters from that two methods. Then if you know about lambda expressions, then:

```
mbox myMboxDelegate = new mBox(() =>
{
   msgboz1();
   msbox2();
});

myMBoxDelegate();
```

Or try:

```
mbox myMboxDelegate = new mBox();
myMboxDelegate += msgboz1();
myMboxDelegate += msbox2();
myMboxDelegate();
```